# Why does F# have such a convoluted comparison operator?

Tags: f#, comparison-operators

On one hand comparing types is overly restrictive i.e. `3 > 1m` is not possible because types must always be the same. On the other hand when implementing a custom comparison it is strangely overly liberal because I must do unboxing as in the example:

```
interface System.IComparable with
      member x.CompareTo yobj =
          match yobj with
          | :? MyThing as y -> compare x.Stamp y.Stamp
          | _ -> invalidArg "yobj" "cannot compare values of different types"
```

Additionally the static member `op_GreaterThan` is completely ignored.

It does not make sense to me why it should not be possible to compare decimals to integers, furthermore it **is** possible to use SRTP to call op_GreaterThan.

What was the reason for this design?

Comment: First let's identify the problem. Overly restrictive is not the problem. Comparison operations are a model of ordered sets and it's natural that they require the same types.

Unfortunately, .Net equality and comparison is very confused, with both untyped IComparable and generic IComparable<T>. Really .Net needs to move to the generic one, but it's been very slow to do this.

Comment: Couldn't you argue that both are a member of the set of real numbers? Mathematically this is correct. Also why not use op_GreaterThan instead of IComparable?

Comment: in case of numbers, sure. But you often compare also things like strings etc, and once you start creating exceptions, you end up with confusing codebase

Comment: @alakfq the set of integers can be considered a subset of the real numbers, but there is a casting happening in maths just as it would in programming languages that allow for implicit casting. We use the natural injection from integers to real numbers, but usually don't explictly state it to save space. To give perhaps more detail than you are asking for: this injection would take the integer 3 to the rational number 3 (the set (a,b) where a,b are integers such that a=3b) and the rational number 3 to the real number 3 (the set of sequences of rational numbers (q_i) such that q_i -> 3).

Comment: So if you "consider 3 as a real number" and then compare it with the real number pi, you are then comparing (3 as a real number) with pi, so while it may appear that you are comparing an integer with a real number, really you are comparing two real numbers.

Comment: @CharlesRoddie I understand but why is it unreasonable to do the same implicit casting in the language if mathematical laws are all obeyed? I see no value being able to upcast a numeric to IComparable other than integration with HashSet which seamingly violates F#

Comment: @CharlesRoddie I guess my question boils down to 'why not like Haskell?'